# React Native installation not working for me

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I bootstrapped my React Native app using the command:

```
react-native init AwesomeApp
```

Then, I tried running the iOS simulator :

```
cd AwesomeApp
react-native run-ios
```

This gave a **Build Failed** error:

> An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeApp.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I then opened up the project in XCode and tried manually running the simulator there. The build failed there too.

Please advise. Anyone else run into similar issues?

I am using

react-native-cli: 2.01

react-native: 0.55.3

react: 16.3.1

xcode: 8.3.1

macOS: 10.12.6

I've also tried downgrading the react-native version, but am still getting the same build failures.

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading Xcode.  current version is 9.3.  I just initialized a new project and it booted up with no issues.  macOS being out of date should be less of an issue, but 10.13.4 is the current release.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) page,

> If you have already installed Xcode on your system, make sure it is version 9.4 or newer.